# Inheriting aliases inside UNIX /usr/bin/script

Tags: unix, shell, environment-variables, scope

The UNIX "/usr/bin/script" command will create a running transcript of your shell session (see "man script" for more info).

However, when *inside* a script instance, it seems to forget the parent shell's env vars, aliases, etc.

The following example demonstrates how the "ll" alias I define is ignored inside "script":

```
zsh> mkdir temp
zsh> cd temp

zsh> alias "ll=ls -alF"

zsh> ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 me   mygroup    4096 Feb 18 13:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x  28 me   mygroup    8192 Feb 18 13:32 ../

zsh> script a.out
Script started, file is a.out
```

> $ ll
>
> ```
> zsh: command not found: ll
> ```

```
$ exit
Script done, file is a.out

zsh> ll
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 me   mygroup    4096 Feb 18 13:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x  28 me   mygroup    8192 Feb 18 13:32 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 me   mygroup     182 Feb 18 13:32 a.out
```

So, how can I get the "script" process to inherit the env settings from the parent shell?

[EDIT:] Okay, env vars are *not* forgotten. Just the aliases. Re-sourcing the .profile or something would work... but how can I make that happen **automatically**?

Comment: Wasn't "script" a built-in in csh?  Maybe ksh's version opens a login shell instead of a normal shell?

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the script command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works OK when I start it under bash. Maybe there's something in your zsh configuration that's mucking it up, or it's not sourcing your zsh's startup files. You could try:
script -c zsh

Which may force it to start a new zsh shell and have it source your zsh config files.

Comment: Using -c switch fails with help msg... usage: script [ -a ] [ typescript ]

Comment: Huh... switched to bash shell, defined alias, invoked /usr/bin/script, and tried to use alias. It failed with error message, "zsh: command not found: ll"

So, apparently script forks off using the shell defined in passwd, but it won't source the user's local config file??? (for zsh, at least)

Comment: Agreed, on another box where I have bash defined as default shell, aliases are inherited into /usr/bin/script. 

So... the problem I see is unique to zsh (and maybe others?)... but bash works okay.

Comment: Having ksh defined as user's default shell in passwd also works correctly. Seems like this must be a deficiency in zsh or simply a config option. Hmmmmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

An alias isn't an environment variable.  You could source your `.profile` or where ever you set up the alias.  Also take a look at the $SHELL environment variable.

The `script` command isn't terribly complicated.  It wouldn't be too difficult to replicate and make it work the way you expect.

Comment: Yah, I did try to say "env settings" and all.

Having to re-source the .profile would be okay if you can 'splain how to make it happen automatically upon invocation of /usr/bin/script. Don't want to force the user to remind himself.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Jon Ericson, aliases are *not* part of the environment.  You will find all your environment in your script.

To get all your aliases in the script, you can save them in a file then reload them:

```
    $ alias myls="ls -lCF"
    $ alias -L >/tmp/alias.zsh
    $ script
    $ . /tmp/alias.zsh
    $ myls
```

If you put your aliases in a file called `.zshrc` in your home directory it will automatically be loaded.

Comment: Okay... that's fine. I understand how to source the .profile or an personal alias script you show manually. But what I really want is to see that source action happen *automatically* without bugging the user.

Comment: And yes, while .zshrc is indeed automatically loaded at login, it is *not* loaded by the /usr/bin/script. Just because I manually defined "ll" in my example for clarity doesn't mean I'm not aware of how to establish per-user config files.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of an alias for zsh ... if you place the alias(es) in 
.zshenv (rather than .zshrc) it should be executed on your behalf automatically.

I know this is an old thread, but sometimes people read old threads ;>

```
alias foo='print FOO'
[khb@vm]~% foo
FOO
[khb@vm]~% script
Script started, file is typescript
[khb@vm]~% foo
zsh: command not found: foo
zsh: use 'exit' to exit.
[khb@vm]~% exit
Script done, file is typescript
[khb@vm]~% mv .bork .zshenv
[khb@vm]~% foo
FOO
[khb@vm]~% script
Script started, file is typescript
[khb@vm]~% foo
FOO
[khb@vm]~% 
 zsh: use 'exit' to exit.
Script done, file is typescript
[khb@vm]~%
```