# Subprocess opened with PIPE still reading input from terminal

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen, file-descriptor

**Python App**

My Python 3.6.8 app runs on CentOS 7.6, and:

- Provides a GUI using Kivy 11.1.1.
- Opens a sub-process from someone else.
- The sub-process provides a custom shell.
- When opened with pipes as below, the sub-process still reads from the terminal.
- It ignores my app's commands to stdin.
- But my app does receive output from the sub-process via the pipe.

**Sub-Process**

- The sub-process controls a device.
- It normally provides an interactive shell.
- I need to control it from my app.
- To launch it, I invoke a compiled binary.
- It uses some Perl modules.
- Its workings are unknown to me.

**Popen Command**

I launch the sub-process from the main thread with this command:

```
launch_cmd = "{} {} {} {}".format(path_of_compiled_binary, opt1, opt2, opt3)
self.myproc = subprocess.Popen(launch_cmd.split(), shell=False,
    cwd=self.testing_dir, close_fds=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env,
    bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, preexec_fn=self.ignore_sigint)
```

**Write Command**

I try to give the sub-process commands with

```
cmd = self.generate_cmd()
cmd = cmd + "\n"
bytes_sent = self.myproc.stdin.write(cmd)
self.myproc.stdin.flush()
```

- The number *bytes_sent* is as expected.
- The sub-process ignores this input.
- But it will do the same command if entered into the terminal from which my app was launched.

**File Descriptors**

- When launched as above, the sub-process eventually has these file descriptors.
- This is at the stage when I need it to run my commands:

`

```
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 0 -> pipe:[58635]
l-wx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 1 -> pipe:[58636]
l-wx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 2 -> pipe:[58636]
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 3 -> /dev/null
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 4 -> path_of_compiled_binary
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 5 -> /dev/tty
l-wx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 6 -> /dev/tty
lrwx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 7 -> socket:[59509]
lrwx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 8 -> /dev/ttyACM0
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 9 -> /tmp/par-64656d6f/temp-15579/inc/lib/PDL/IO/Pic.pm
```

Comment: It sounds like your process is reading from the terminal instead of `stdin`. Canonical tools only do this for passwords and similar, but who knows what your tool may do. You can fake a terminal for programs invoked via python with  `pexpect`

Comment: Thanks, @that-other-guy, pexpect sounds interesting. The IPC here involves no passwords, just simple commands to a custom shell.

Comment: You can check whether this theory is correct by running `["script", "-c", "your shell command here", "/dev/null"]`, since `script` happens to spawn a tty and relay messages from/to standard streams

Comment: Not quite getting it. Would Popen invoke ["script", "-c", "launch_cmd", "/dev/null"]? Then could I write to the pipe? Could this solve the problem?

Comment: If the problem is that the program reads from the tty instead of stdin, then yes. If the problem is something else, then no. (Obviously quoting `"launch_cmd"` would not use the value of your variable)

Comment: @that-other-guy, I coded the `script` idea and tested. It looks fine, but I don't have the device here. I sent it to my partner to test in his temporary home office.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215395/discussion-between-badams-and-that-other-guy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sub-process reading from tty, not stdin**

The sub-process opens 2 file descriptors to /dev/tty:

```
lr-x------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 5 -> /dev/tty
l-wx------. 1 demo demo 64 Jun  5 10:44 6 -> /dev/tty
```

- @that-other-guy suggested that the sub-process reads from one of these instead of stdin.
- Apparently 5, since its mode is read only?

**/usr/bin/script utility**

Another suggestion from @that-other-guy:

- Use `script` to launch the sub-process.
- The [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562370/inheriting-aliases-inside-unix-usr-bin-script) utility is designed to capture a shell session into a live transcript.
- The [-c](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) option spawns any given command instead of a shell.
- Providing /dev/null for the file argument says to forget the transcript.

Re-coding with script:

```
launch_cmd = "{} {} {} {}".format(path_of_compiled_binary, opt1, opt2, opt3)
script_argv = ["/usr/bin/script", "-c", launch_cmd, "/dev/null"]
self.myproc = subprocess.Popen(script_argv, shell=False,
    cwd=self.testing_dir, close_fds=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env,
    bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, preexec_fn=self.ignore_sigint)
```

**How it works**

- `script` spawns the sub-process and interacts with it in a pseudoterminal.
- `script` reads stdin from the pipe and echoes it into its pseudoterminal for the sub-process to read.
- Now it doesn't matter if the sub-process is reading the terminal on 5 instead of stdin on 0.

This change overcame the problem. The sub-process now receives commands from the app.